# Multiple SSH windows?

Tags: ssh

I've been using an ubuntu vps with MATE and xrdp installed and I decided to upgrade to a dedicated server, now by advice of others, I'm not using any gui environments or xrdp to save on computing power.
 I know how to "walk around" in the ssh console, however I plan to host a few gameservers, and using a gui environment was super easy for that, just double click the start_gameserver.sh file and it opens a new terminal with the gameserver console (and I could open as many instances as I wanted), how do I do this with ssh? And also see the gameserver console input / output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, with ssh, you would do the same thing.

```
# ./start_gameserver.sh
```

And it would run. You could then ssh into the server multiple times and each would run in its own session.

The downside, of course, is that once your ssh session closes, your game server would likely be killed. And, it would be kind of cumbersome to run an ssh instance for each and every game server.

You can use [tmux](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/) to run multiple interactive sessions over one ssh connection, plus resume those sessions *between* connections. You can split screens, run them in the background, and do other nifty stuff from ssh.

Comment: +1 for `tmux`, but I would prefer to create a service that will run the script, it is not so complicated task.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different options here actually. It really depends on the game server and if you "need" the console to remain open. You could set up the server as a service via `systemd` and start the servers in the way services are intended to be started. This likely is the best idea.

If you're set on having access to each console, you could use jobs and just fork the game server to the background. doing so would allow you to swap between the various open jobs using `jobs`, `fg` and `CTRL-Z`.

```
# ./start_gameserver.sh &
```

You could also install either `screen` or `tmux`.

You can get more details about jobs with `jobs --help` as well as fg with `fg --help` and you can find screen and tmux in the repository.

Though, based only on the limited information you gave, I highly recommend you do some searching to learn how to setup and use systemd to manager the services.

Comment: Thank you! i find tmux to be easier to use than setting up jobs and services, but I will still learn about them.